# Github syncing seems to work but still gives an error

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

We have a corporate github page and I have access to just the one project. I can push to and pull from, I can make new branches and I can merge those branches back in, but whenever I push the sync button manually when there aren't any changes I get this error.

> The repository does not seem to exist anymore. You may not have
>   access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.

I read on another stack overflow it could be a caching error when I switched from my personal github profile to my professional, so I logged out and logged back in.

I also verified there weren't any strange characters in my local path as another stack overflow suggested, it is just my documents folder and only letters/numbers in my username.

Comment: Grab the `git://` URL from Github, and do `git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here`. I'd bet the repo or the organization got renamed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it appears I can still branch from it and it does auto-sync. Its just when I manually try to sync. I am starting to wonder if it is something to do with our internal firewalls